# Что делают функции begin() и end()

Tags: c++, массивы, шаблоны-с++

Нигде не могу найти описание функций `begin()` и `end()`, для чего они нужны?
     Если можно напишите *пример* пожалуйста :)

Comment: [Нигде не могу найти описание функций begin() и end()](http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=begin&button=).

Comment: Какие "функции begin() и end()"? `std::begin()` и `std::end()`? Или методы контейнеров?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Шаблоны функций `std::begin` и `std::end` просто вызывают методы `begin()` и `end()` у своего аргумента и возвращают полученный результат. Но при этом они специализированы особым образом для аргументов типа "массив": `std::begin` возвращает указатель на начало массива, а `std::end` указатель на воображаемый элемент за концом массива.

Эти функции предназначены для унификации интерфейса между стандартными контейнерами, обыкновенными массивами и `std::initializer_list`. Начиная с С++17 в этот комплект также входят шаблоны функции `std::data`, `std::size` и `std::empty`, служащие аналогичным целям и реализованные аналогичным образом.

Пользуясь этими функциями вы можете писать унифицированный generic шаблонный код, который сможет работать как со стандартными контейнерами, так и с обычными массивами, и с `std::initializer_list` без необходимости вручную писать специализированные версии для этих особых случаев

```
template <typename T> void print(const T &c)
{
  if (!std::empty(c))
  {
    std::cout << "Size: " << std::size(c) << std::endl;
    for (auto it = std::begin(c); it != std::end(c); ++it)
      std::cout << *it << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
}

int main()
{
  int a[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
  print(a);

  std::list<double> l = { 5, 6, 7, 8 };
  print(l);

  auto il = { "10", "11", "12", "13", "14" };
  print(il);
}
```

За пределами generic кода необходимости в использовании этих функций нет, но использовать их по-прежнему можно и иногда даже весьма удобно.

Answer (score 2):

Итератор, указывающий на первый элемент в контейнере, и *за* последний элемент.

```
int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
for(auto i = begin(a); i != end(a); ++i)
    cout << *i << endl;
```

Примерно так. Если вы о свободных функциях.

Функции-члены делают то же самое:

```
vector<int> a {1,2,3,4,5};
for(auto i = a.begin(); i != a.end(); ++i)
    cout << *i << endl;
```