# Получение первого элемента vector

Tags: c++, vector, итераторы

Не могу понять в чём разница.

```
vector<int> a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
cout<<*a.begin(); 
cout<<*begin(a);
```

Чем отличаются два этих способа получения первого элемента vector.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/770320/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-begin-%D0%B8-end

Comment: Да по сути ничем. Вторая вызывает первую.

Answer (score 1):

Да по сути ничем. Вторая вызывает первую. А оптимизатор все это как вызов удаляет...

Как говорится, найдите отличие в коде VC++ 2019:

```
; 20   :     cout<<*a.begin();

    mov edx, DWORD PTR [rbx]
    lea rcx, OFFSET FLAT:?cout@std@@3V?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@1@A ; std::cout
    call    ??6?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEAAAEAV01@H@Z ; std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<

; 21   :     cout<<*begin(a);

    mov edx, DWORD PTR [rbx]
    lea rcx, OFFSET FLAT:?cout@std@@3V?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@1@A ; std::cout
    call    ??6?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEAAAEAV01@H@Z ; std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<
```

Вот [описание](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin):

> Returns an iterator to the beginning of the given range.
> Returns exactly c.begin(), which is typically an iterator to the beginning of the sequence represented by c. If C is a standard Container, this returns C::iterator when c is not const-qualified, and C::const_iterator otherwise.